# I can`t to add social media element in this background

Tags: html, css

I try add this element [ social media buttons ] :

```
  $redColor: rgba(244,67,54,1);
$blueColor:rgba(33,150,243,1);

.flex-center {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50vh;

  background: #000;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.icon-3d {
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: icon3d 200ms 10;
  animation: icon3d 200ms 10;
  color: #fff;
  &:hover {
    -webkit-animation: icon3d 200ms infinite;
          animation: icon3d 200ms infinite;
  }
}

@keyframes icon3d {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 5px 4px $redColor, -5px -6px $blueColor;
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow: -5px -6px $redColor, 5px 4px $blueColor;
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 5px -4px $redColor, -8px 4px $blueColor;
  }
  75% {
    text-shadow: -8px -4px $redColor, -5px -4px $blueColor;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: -5px 0 $redColor, 5px -4px $blueColor;
  }
} 
<blink> <div class="flex-center">
  <i class="fa fa-github fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-gitlab fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bitbucket fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-git fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
</div>

<div class="flex-center">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
</div></blink>
```

in this background : https://codepen.io/GARDFIELD3/pen/wJVNYq 
I don`t know how can I add this html+css code in my pen from codepen. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

1. The background `<canvas>` element occupies the entire vertical height of the frame. This ends up pushing the `.flex-center` `<div>` off the bottom of the screen.
2. You haven't loaded the CSS files needed to use the Font Awesome (`fa-whatever`) classes, so your `<i>` elements have no graphics associated with them.

Comment: well, and how to solve the first problem? I need solution not the problem because I am beginner .. thank you very much :D